# Add a second content database to Sharepoint 2010 farm with existing Remote BLOB

Tags: content-database

We have a SharePoint 2010 farm with 2 web front-end servers and 1 sql server database.  The database server this farm uses is typical single instance sql server where all the databases, including content database, are stored.

The sql server instance is set up with remote BLOB, so all binary files are chunk-saved into a disk on the sql server OS.

This is a production system we've set up a couple of years ago and currently the content database has surpassed 100gb.

This isn't a big emergency but I'm planning now to create a second instance of on the same sql server to attach another content database.  I'd like to do another sql server instance because this way I can use another drive attached to the OS.  This second data drive will give us more space as the first one is several months away from being full.  I will create a database in that instance and follow the directions [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628965%28v=office.14%29.aspx), which is basically how to add a new content-database to the existing web application.

Do I have to configure remote BLOB again for a new SQL server instance?  Whether it does or does not, is this a typical scenario / plan?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the new SQL server, You have to configure it for RBS as well. You have to follow all the steps which you did on exisitng server.You just need configure the RBS on 2nd SQL server because on WFE it is already setup.

- Enable FILESTREAM on the database server.
- Provision a BLOB store for each content database
- Enable RBS for each content database
- Assign db_owner permissions to the web application
- Test the RBS installation

Another thing, RBS is basically per content Database. If you add more content DB and want to use RBS on them then you have to configure those DBs.

[Set a content database to use RBS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748605(v=office.14).aspx)

[Install and configure RBS with FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748631.aspx)